# Using current user to initialize ForeignKey user in Django CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm getting an error:

```
AttributeError at /courses/create/
'CourseStudentForm' object has no attribute 'user'
```

When I try to create a new object by setting it's user field to the current user:

```
class CourseStudentCreate(CreateView):
    model = CourseStudent
    fields = ['semester', 'block', 'course', 'grade']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('quests:quests')

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = form.save(commit=False)
        data.user = self.request.user
        data.save()
        return super(CourseStudentCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

This is the model:

```
class CourseStudent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester)
    block = models.ForeignKey(Block)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    grade = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

The form displays correctly, but when I submit I get the error.

ANSWER:

From here:
[Pass current user to initial for CreateView in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238663/pass-current-user-to-initial-for-createview-in-django)

If I want to keep user as a required field, it works if I change `form_valid` to:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    return super(CourseStudentCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

The cause of the error is described by Burhan Khalid below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because you are missing a required field from your form class; recall that model form validation will also [validate the model instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform):

> Validation on a `ModelForm`
>
> There are two main steps involved in validating a `ModelForm`:
>
> ```
> Validating the form
> Validating the model instance
> ```

In your class, the inherited `post` method is calling `is_valid()`:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance with the passed
    POST variables and then checked for validity.
    """
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

You can see that it only calls `form_valid()` if `is_valid()` returns true; in your case it can't return true because you have a required attribute missing.

You can solve this problem easily by making the `user` foreign key optional in your model.

Comment: Thank you.  So, if I want to keep user as a required field, then I should set `blank=True` on the field?

Comment: Or, if I create `class CourseStudentForm(forms.ModelForm):` can I initialize the user value there?

Comment: Not `blank=True`, you need to set `null=True` (otherwise the database validation will fail).

Comment: But I want to keep the field as required.  I found it and edited the answer.